# Even Fibonacci Numbers

Tags: javascript, fibonacci

I have write this code

```js
function fiboEvenSum(n) {
  const array = [1, 2];
  const array2 = [];
  let sum = 0;
  for (let i = 2; i < n; i++) {
    num = array[i - 2] + array[i - 1];
    array.push(num);
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] % 2 == 0) {
      array2.push(array[i]);
    }
  }
  for (let j = 0; j < array2.length; j++) {
    sum += array2[j];
  }
  return sum;
}
const al = fiboEvenSum(8)
console.log(al)
```

i want to print the even numbers of Fibonacci Numbers. But the tutorial (which i do) dont agree with me it says that i am wrong. I have any issues?

Comment: You are returning `sum`. Why not return `array2`?

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using 2 for loops in your solution. In order to optimize the performance you can achieve this via a do-while loop instead

```js
function printEvenFibonacciPrinter(value) {
  let fibonacciSequence = [0, 1];
  let evenNumbers = [];

  while (fibonacciSequence[fibonacciSequence.length - 1] <= value) {
    let nextNumber = fibonacciSequence[fibonacciSequence.length - 1] + fibonacciSequence[fibonacciSequence.length - 2];
    fibonacciSequence.push(nextNumber);

    if (nextNumber % 2 === 0) {
      evenNumbers.push(nextNumber);
    }
  }    
  console.log('FibonacciSequence : '+fibonacciSequence);
  return evenNumbers;

}
console.log('Even fibonacci numbers '+printEvenFibonacciPrinter(5))
```